# Распарить HTML и положить в массив отдельным элементом

Tags: php

Спарсил HTML. Как вытащить все, что находится между тегом  и добавить отдельным элементом в массив?

**Вот HTML код:**

```
  <br><span class="mobi-row"></span><span class="mobi-row"></span><span class="mobi-row"></span><span><a href="/">Тяга</a></span><span>он уходил,она вслед кричала</span><span class="time">03:19</span><span class="bitrate">128 kbps</span><span class="size">3.0 МБ</span>
<span
  class="time">03:17</span><span class="bitrate">128 kbps</span><span class="size">3.0 МБ</span><span class="mobi-row"></span><span class="mobi-row"></span><span class="mobi-row"></span><span><a href="/></span><span>Он уходил, она вслед кричала</span><span class="time">03:40</span>
  <span
    class="bitrate">207 kbps</span><span class="size">5.5 МБ</span><span class="time">05:35</span><span class="bitrate">320 kbps</span><span class="size">13.4 МБ</span><span class="time">06:03</span><span class="bitrate">320 kbps</span><span class="size">13.8 МБ</span>
    <span
      class="time">05:35</span><span class="bitrate">320 kbps</span><span class="size">13.4 МБ</span><span class="time">04:30</span><span class="bitrate">192 kbps</span><span class="size">6.2 МБ</span><span class="time">05:35</span><span class="bitrate">320 kbps</span>
      <span
        class="size">13.4 МБ</span>
```

Написал так, но не могу сделать регулярку и добавление в массив.

$element3 - здесь хранится мой html код.

```
foreach ($element3 as $val2) // Первая переменная - массив. Вторая переменная - значение.
{
$patt = "class='size'\>(.*?)\<\/span>"; // регулярка 
preg_match($patt,$val2,$match); // 1 - регулярка. 2 Источник. 3. Куда поместить результат
echo $match[1]; // вывод с массива
```

Answer (score 0):

Неизвестно зачем тут цикл, по этому оставил `foreach`, а html поместил в массив (может действительно это массив с разными кусками html):

```
$element3[] = <<<HTML
  <br><span class="mobi-row"></span><span class="mobi-row"></span><span class="mobi-row"></span><span><a href="/">Тяга</a></span><span>он уходил,она вслед кричала</span><span class="time">03:19</span><span class="bitrate">128 kbps</span><span class="size">3.0 МБ</span><span class="time">03:17</span><span class="bitrate">128 kbps</span><span class="size">3.0 МБ</span><span class="mobi-row"></span><span class="mobi-row"></span><span class="mobi-row"></span><span><a href="/"></span><span>Он уходил, она вслед кричала</span><span class="time">03:40</span><span class="bitrate">207 kbps</span><span class="size">5.5 МБ</span><span class="time">05:35</span><span class="bitrate">320 kbps</span><span class="size">13.4 МБ</span><span class="time">06:03</span><span class="bitrate">320 kbps</span><span class="size">13.8 МБ</span><span class="time">05:35</span><span class="bitrate">320 kbps</span><span class="size">13.4 МБ</span><span class="time">04:30</span><span class="bitrate">192 kbps</span><span class="size">6.2 МБ</span><span class="time">05:35</span><span class="bitrate">320 kbps</span><span class="size">13.4 МБ</span>
HTML;

foreach ($element3 as $val2) {
  $patt = '/size">([0-9.]+ МБ)<\//';
  preg_match_all($patt,$val2,$match);
  print_r($match[1]);
}
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку " preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in". Как я понял, входные данные в виде массива, а должны быть в строке. Поправьте, если ошибся.

Comment: Если просто скопировать ваш код, то выдает "Cannot use object of type simple_html_dom_node as array "

Comment: $element3 - я получил путем парсинга simple_html_dom по тегу span. Получился видать массив. Походу его нужно в строку переделать.

Comment: @LEX, проблема в том, что у меня никаких ошибок не выдает

Comment: @LEX, вставьте в тело вопроса хотя бы часть того, что у вас находится в `$element3`

Comment: Видите в вопросе "ВОТ HTML КОД" это и есть содержимое $element3

Comment: @LEX, Если у вас там просто строка, то цикл не нужен. Но судя по ошибке у вас там не строка, а объект ...

Comment: А что делать с объектом тогда?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65511/discussion-between-lex-and-medvedevdev).

Comment: @LEX, объект тоже надо перебирать, но что бы перебирать, надо понимать что там за объект, а то мы так обсуждение того что происходит с перебором объекта растянем на неделю. По этому я и просил сделать `print_r($element3)` и скинуть их хотя бы частично, что бы можно было понять какой цикл надо написать (и надо ли), что бы добраться до нужной строки.

Comment: Мучался почти сутки с этой проблемой. В итоге спарсил не массив или объект, а тупо нарезал строку регулярками. :) 7 параметров быстрее найти и записать в массив, чем готовый массив обрабатывать и мучаться:) НО это чисто для меня